# How to read in spaces with if stream in c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I need to read in a txt file that has 20 rows (ROWS = 20) and 40 columns (COLS = 40)
But so far when I read in the file it does not recognize the spaces. This is what I have so far:

```
void readMaze(string file) {
    if stream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(file);
    char input;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
           inputFile >> input;
           switch(put) {
               case 'X':
                   maze[i][j] = WALL;
                   break;
               case 'S':
                   maze[i][j] = START;
                   break;
               case 'C':
                   maze[i][j] = CHEESE;
                   break;
               case ' ':
                   maze[i][j] = SPACE;
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
       }
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: stream i/o ignores whitespace - usually a good thing.  I think you want to try binary i/o.

Comment: Use `std::getline()` to read a line of text terminated by a newline. That's what it's there for.

Comment: `if stream inputFile;` .. did you mean `ifstream inputFile;` ..?

Comment: Oh ok:) So I haven't use that before.. what would it look like?

Comment: okay so if i use the getline() how would i go about dividing up the cstring into individual chars that i can read/use/reference later?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN more accurately, `operator>>` ignores whitespace, unless you use the [`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) manipulator.